# PhoneGap Build Android Icons

Tags: phonegap-build, android-icons

I'm struggling to get my PhoneGap Build android icons to show up properly.  My iOS icons are working perfectly.  Here's the Config.xml:

```
<icon src="icon/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<icon src="icon/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<icon src="icon/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<icon src="icon/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
<icon src="icon/xxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" />
```

And here's the folder structure:

[image]

Comment: You say "show up properly". Do they show up at all? What happens exactly? And do you have a default icon? You need a default icon and splash screen for these to work properly.

Comment: I was able to get the icon to show by using the web interface to set the default - even though it is set in my config.xml.  Android splash screen still doesn't show up.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have default icon and splash screens and you shouldn't set a platform for these.

See here: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens

Comment: That example has the following for splash screen, which is exactly what I have but still doesn't work